# Can I rearrange a quotation?

Tags: quotes, quotations, formatting

I am quoting a book (The Origins of the Final Solution, Christopher Browning), and am wondering if I can put the quote 'the other way round':

The actual quote is this:

> "Lebensraum and Final Solution, Hitler's twin obsessions" (Browning, 427)

And I want to incorporate it into this sentence:

> It follows that from Browning's point of view the Holocaust evolved, with "Hitler's twin obsessions...Lebensraum and Final Solution" (Browning, 427) acting as the drive behind this evolution.

Is it acceptable to put one clause behind the other if an ellipsis is used? Or should I try to restructure my sentence so the quotation is unadulterated?

Comment: You either incorporate the quote or you don't, The only allowance is removing or adjusting a word at the beginning with square brackets. Why not: It follows from X's point of view that the Holocaust evolved with "A and B, Hitler's twin obsessions".  Apposition is perfectly understandable. The ellipsis is an awkward device and it is not used for re-arranging.

Comment: This is a question about academic practice. Expert answers are more likely to be found at [academia.se]. Bear in mind their guidelines for submission which, like ours, require you to include in your question the results of your own attempts to find the answer and why the results were not adequate.

Comment: @MetaEd so how can I improve this? Or is it really completely off topic?

Comment: It's really completely off topic. Consider that if you were quoting a German source the right answer wouldn't be any different. There's no question here about the grammar of the English language.

Answer (score 2):

An ellipsis implies that a portion is being omitted from a complete quotation.  It would be misleading to use an ellipsis to restructure the quote.

[From MLA (Modern Language Association)](http://writingcommons.org/open-text/research-methods-methodologies/integrate-evidence/incorporate-evidence/613-omitting-words-from-a-direct-quotation-mla) style:

> Ellipsis points are used to represent an omission from a direct quotation

In your case, you're not just omitting from a *direct quotation*, you're also altering the structure.  You could just quote both parts separately.

> It follows that from Browning's point of view the Holocaust evolved with "Hitler's twin obsessions," "Lebensraum and Final Solution," acting...

Where you would place the citation in a case like this would depend on what style guide you're following, but the second quote should be encapsulated by parenthetical commas, as in the example I used.  You could probably put the second comma after the citation:

> ...evolved with "Hitler's twin obessions," "Lebensraum and Final Solution" (Browning, 427), acting...

Comment: This looks like a good solution; however, I don't think you would need quotes around *Lebensraum and Final Solution*.  You do for the twin obsessions, because that's creative phrasing.  But you don't for the terms that are commonly used by everybody and his cousin.